# How to detect words with space at the end (Regex - C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I have created this Regex Pattern `(?=[Ss]table[ :])(.*)`, which "detect" these words:

```
Stable       <--- Here is one space at the end
stable       <--- Here is one space at the end
Stable:
stable:
```

The Patter does not detect these words which are without space at the end:

```
Stable
stable
```

What should I change to detect and these two Words!

Comment: I don't suppose it's as easy as putting a question mark after the second ending square bracket?

Comment: Maybe `([Ss]table.*)`? If the space and colon are optional, why care about checking for their presence? `.*` can match them as well.

Comment: Why do you need to use lookarounds at all? Is this a complete example of your inputs?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Behind the word, Stable is one sentence. I want to remove "Stable" if one of these options is showing there, but not all the sentences!

Comment: @gunr2171 Behind the word, Stable is one sentence. I want to remove "Stable" if one of these options is showing there, but not all the sentences!

Comment: What do you mean? Please clarify your question by editing it. Adding some code with a test case would help understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 (?=[Ss]table([ :]|$))(.*)
```

Al I have changed is:

```
([ :]|$)
```

That will look ahead for a space, a colon OR **end of line** - assuming you use 'multiline' option.

Answer (score -1):

When you add this in string, for examle with name str:

```
string str= "Stable";
            if (str[str.Length - 1] == ' ')
            {
                your block of code;
            }
```